# Ajax POST request, change css on button if json.object equals to true

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, django

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#quiz-options button').click(function() {
    // Ajax post request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/quiz/check/",
        data: {
            'id' : $(this).val(),
        },
        success: success,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
});

function success(data, status, xmp){    
// Question is correct
if(data.correct == true){
    $('#quiz-options button').val(data.id).addClass("correct");
} 
// Question is wrong
else {
    $(this).addClass("error");
}}
```

My problem is that if I use $('#quiz-options button').val(data.id).addClass("correct"); this line the css is added to every button, and when I try with the secound way with $(this) is do not chanage anything.

I think the problem is that the success function dont have access to $this, however, how do I pass it down to the success function so that I can use it to change the css?

Many thanks.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that `this` in your success function isn't actually your button anymore.  You could pass `this` as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but did not find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture a reference to the button in the click handler to be used in the success callback...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#quiz-options button').click(function() {

        var optionButton = $(this);

        // Ajax post request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/quiz/check/",
            data: {
                'id' : optionButton.val(),
            },
            success: function success(data, status, xmp){ 
                if(data.correct == true){
                    optionButton.val(data.id).addClass("correct");
                } 
                else {
                    optionButton.addClass("error");
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
});
```